# IoT OPC publisher in ANSI C

Tags: azure

The IoT OPC publisher (https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-opc-publisher) connects to an existing OPC server and publishes data from this server to the Azure IoT hub. It's however implement using .NET. 
I could not find a similar functionality using the Azure-Iot-C-SDK (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c) in C99.